# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - Visual Basic (Web)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So, I'm having a slight problem with my code.

I was working on a small school project (recreation of book library) and encountered a problem which I cannot get a grasp of.

So, the user can search for a list of books, and after the list is populated (via DataList control), a small button "Book now" (Reserve) appears which user can click and reserve his book.

This is the code for the DataList control that resides in "Search.aspx"

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="knjigaId" DataSourceID="SearchSqlDataSource" CssClass="searchControl">
                <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="pictureOfFoundBook">
                    <asp:Image ID="pictureOfFoundBook_imageLink" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/GetImage.aspx?knjigaId=" & Eval("knjigaId") & "&img=naslovnica" %>' />
                </div>
                <div class="descriptionOfFoundBook">
                    Naziv: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("naziv") %>' /><br />
                    Godina izdanja: <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("godinaIzdanja") %>' /><br />
                    Broj stranica : <asp:Label ID="brojStranicaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("brojStranica") %>' /><br />
                    Izdava&#269;: <asp:Label ID="NazivIzdavacaLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NazivIzdavaca") %>' /><br />
                    Vrsta tiskovine : <asp:Label ID="NazivVrsteTiskovineLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NazivVrsteTiskovine") %>' /><br />
                    Kategorija: <asp:Label ID="NazivKategorijeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NazivKategorije") %>' /><br /><br />
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="foundBookEditHL_adminOnly" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/admin/knjigeEdit.aspx?knjigaId=" & Eval("knjigaId") %>'>Uredi knjigu</asp:HyperLink><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="rezervacijeButton" runat="server" Text="Rezerviraj" OnClick="rezervacijaClick" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("knjigaId") %>'/><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="rezStatusLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="rezStatusPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <hr />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

I've set the DataList1 control as a Friend sub so I can access the controls in it from another sub;

```
Friend Sub DataList1_ItemCreated(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList1.ItemCreated
    End Sub
```

I was trying to do the following; on the click of a button "rezervacijeButton", a function "rezervacijaClick" runs, which populates the table in the database.

```
Protected Sub rezervacijaClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
            Dim Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ToString)
            Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            Dim sql As New StringBuilder
            Dim rezstatus As Label = DataList1.FindControl("rezStatusLabel")

            sql.Append("INSERT INTO rezervacije(UserName, knjigaId) VALUES (@UserName, @knjigaId)")

            Dim buttonsender As Button = sender
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", User.Identity.Name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("knjigaId", buttonsender.CommandArgument)

            Conn.Open()
            cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString
            cmd.Connection = Conn
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Conn.Close()

            buttonsender.Visible = False
            rezstatus.Text = "aaa"

            'Try
            '    rezstatus.Text = "testing..."
            'Catch ex As Exception
            '    exlabel.Text = "POGREŠKA"
            '    exlabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            'End 
        End Sub
```

The next thing I wanted to do in the function "rezervacijaClick" was to set the text value of the Label (with ID "rezStatusLabel", which resides inside the DataList1 control)  to "SOME TEXT" after the "Reserve" button is clicked.

But after the button click, I get the following error :

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Line 21: 
Line 22:         buttonsender.Visible = False
Line 23:         rezstatus.Text = "aaa"
Line 24: 
Line 25:         'Try
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `rezstatus` object is `Nothing` (`null`).

This is happening because you aren't looking in the right place for your label.

Each record of data you bind to the `DataList` will create a new hierarchy of controls, containers that hold the other controls you have defined in your `ItemTemplate`.

The immediate descendants of `DataList1` will be a collection of `DataListItem` objects and then you will have your controls inside those.

Since we don't know for sure (unless you know you are only binding one record to the `DataList`) which `DataListItem` the desired label will be in, we simply walk backwards up the control tree and find the label from there.

Because you are responding to a button click event in your `rezervacijaClick` method, the parameter `sender` will be of type `Button` and will come from `rezervacijeButton`, so we can use that information to find your label:

```
Dim clickedButton As Button = CType(sender, Button) 'convert the sender parameter to the correct type: Button
Dim buttonParent As Control = clickedButton.Parent 'get a reference to the button's parent control
Dim rezstatus As Label = CType(buttonParent.FindControl(""), Label) 'find the label by ID and convert it to a Label as the return type of FindControl is Control
```

Comment: Good explanation of the OPs misunderstanding how the structure of this control.

Comment: Thanks, I learned this the hard way, it can be confusing at times.

Comment: Excellent, wasn't even aware I could trace back to parent control :/

Comment: @valaya A habit I've got into, which helps immensely when trying to figure problems out, is to open up the documentation page for the specific class I'm working with on MSDN and have a scroll down the list of properties, methods and events to get an idea of what's available to me.

Comment: @Sean Yea, I was trying to do that, but I gotta admit I'm kinda lost whilst searching, especially since I've started with ASP a week ago.

Comment: @valaya You'll get used to it eventually =]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that, instead of using the Button click event, you use the [DataList.ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand.aspx) event.  It will make your life a lot easier.  This event fires whenever a Button is clicked within a row of your DataList control.

This way, you get the index passed in through the `DataListCommandEventArgs` parameter.  then you would just need to update your DataList markup to add the event handler:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="knjigaId" 
    DataSourceID="SearchSqlDataSource" CssClass="searchControl"
    ItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand" >
```

And your handler code would look like this:

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemCommand(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LocalSqlServer").ToString)
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim sql As New StringBuilder

    Dim rezstatus As Label = e.Item.FindControl("rezStatusLabel")

    sql.Append("INSERT INTO rezervacije(UserName, knjigaId) VALUES (@UserName, @knjigaId)")

    Dim buttonsender As Button = e.Item.FindControl("rezervacijeButton")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", User.Identity.Name)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("knjigaId", buttonsender.CommandArgument)

    Conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = sql.ToString
    cmd.Connection = Conn
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Conn.Close()

    buttonsender.Visible = False
    rezstatus.Text = "aaa"
End Sub
```